# Haskell - Trying to create a function to find the factorial of odd numbers

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, factorial

```
fact :: Int -> Int 
fact n
    |n < 0 = 0
    |n == 0 = 1
    |n > 0 && n `mod` 2 == 1 = fact (n-1) * n
    |n > 0 && n `mod` 2 == 0 = n-1
```

When I enter an odd number for example: fact 5 will give 15, as it should 1 * 3 * 5 = 15. However I realized that if I do fact 7 or any other odd number, it only multiplies the first two odd numbers. How do I get the function to multiply all the odd numbers and not just the first 2. Eg. fact 7 = 35 (ie. 3 * 5). Also note, that if an even number is entered, it will work out the factorial of all the odd numbers up until and not including the even number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is that your case for an even number is `n-1`, which means that when you get to an odd number you're really just doing

```
n * (n - 1 - 1)
```

When what you want is

n * n-2 * n-4 ...

So try this instead

```
fact :: Integer -> Integer -- Overflows 
fact n
    |n < 0 = 0
    |n == 0 || n == 1 = 1
    |n `mod` 2 == 1 = fact (n-2) * n
    |n `mod` 2 == 0 = fact (n-1)
```

I also took the liberty of removing some redundant logic. Here we decrement by two if it's odd, so 5 -> 3. And in the even case we decrement by one to end up on an odd number and that recurse on that.

Comment: I think for odd numbers greater than one it actually does `fact (n-1) * n where fact x = x-1` which is `fact (n-1) * n where fact (n-1) = (n-1)-1` which is `((n-1)-1) * n` which is `n * (n-2)`.

Comment: All the numbers that I've tried equals 0, does it have something to do with the n-2? In my code, when I tried n-2 I didn't have n < 0 = 0 and the answer went into the negatives.

Comment: @jellybean_232 Yep, I added a check for n == 1

Comment: @jellybean_232 It catches it at the case where `n == 1` so that it doesn't decrement 2 past it to -1

Comment: @jellybean_232 No problem, feel free to check my answer to mark the question as closed

Answer (score 4):

This reminds me of the famous [Evolution of a Haskell Programmer](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html). Paraphrasing the tenured professor's answer:

```
factorialOfOdds :: Integer -> Integer
factorialOfOdds n = product [1,3..n]
```